# Confusion matrix doesn't match evaluation

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm training with TensorFlow a CNN for image classification on dataset Food-101 and I reach a test accuracy of about 80% (I use **model.evaluate()**).

The issue I have is that when I plot the **confusion matrix** of the 3 classes involved this is very different and have maximum 40% on the main diagonal.

I could understand it if at least 1 of the 3 classes was around 100%, because I would expect the averaged accuracy to raise even with bad results in the other predictions. But in this case none of them is neither similar to what I achieve during evaluation.

I tried to plot the confusion matrix with training data, with which I reached more than 90% accuracy during the learning process, and also this is not correct.

Comment: Impossible to answer without details or code.

Comment: Those are the figures: [accuracy](https://imgur.com/a/bqjiqZZ) and [test confusion matrix](https://imgur.com/a/yM81enw). Look the difference between test accuracy and predictions. Is it possible?